# SQL Query to return all entries in where statement, including duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run a query in SQL (SSMS) in which I provide thousands of customer ID's and ask for the make and model of the cars they lease.
Here is some sample data of a case with 7 customer ID's, some being duplicates.

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Make, Model
FROM [Database]
WHERE Customer_ID IN (1,2,51,11,23,2,11)
ORDER BY
    CASE Customer_ID
        WHEN 1 THEN 1
        WHEN 2 THEN 2
        WHEN 51 THEN 3
        WHEN 11 THEN 4
        WHEN 23 THEN 5
        WHEN 2 THEN 6
        WHEN 11 THEN 7
    END
```

My current result: 5 unique rows where the duplicate IDs are omitted (2 and 11)

```
Customer_ID Make    Model
1           Ford    Focus
2           Honda   CRV
51          Ford    Raptor
11          Toyota  Corolla
23          Jeep    Wrangler
```

My desired output: 7 rows with duplicates

```
Customer_ID Make    Model
1           Ford    Focus
2           Honda   CRV
51          Ford    Raptor
11          Toyota  Corolla
23          Jeep    Wrangler
2           Honda   CRV
11          Toyota  Corolla
```

I'm unsure why the duplicates are being omitted when I'm not using "DISTINCT". Looking for any tips and please consider I'd ideally like a 'strong' fix as this is for thousands of entries.

Comment: Do you have data example of what is in the table?  You are not doing anything to limit the results so you should be getting the dupes as well.

Comment: It is unclear why do you not get ducllicate values your query as it is would show them, if they exist in the table

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, this is what I'm running without any other limitations but I am stuck with only unique values.. I've been on this for an hour but I can't even find someone with the same issue to follow their advice. I've even gone back to the basics of restarting from scratch, reformatting the query, etc. and I cannot get all the results

Comment: Unclear why you want this but you need to join not use `IN`. What version of SQL Server? If 2022 then you could use `SELECT Customer_ID, Make, Model
FROM [Database] d
JOIN string_split('1,2,51,11,23,2,11', ',',1) ss ON ss.value = d.Customer_ID
ORDER BY ss.ordinal`

Comment: It's for reporting in my business, the duplicates matter for reasons in other areas.  It's version 19.1

Comment: 19.1 is SSMS not SQL Server. What does `select @@VERSION` return?

Comment: Sorry - 2019. Regardless, using string split worked and returned all entries. I'm still unsure of the root of this issue since I didn't use DUPLICATE or other limitations but it's working now for my intended  use

Comment: If there is only one `Customer` row with `Customer_ID = 2`, the condition `Customer_ID IN (1,2,3)` is **no more and no less true** than `Customer_ID IN (1,2,2,3)`. The `Customer` row is included in the result, but is not duplicated.  If you had instead coded `FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(2),(3)) V(ID) JOIN Customers C ON C.Customer_ID = V.ID)`, the `VALUES` part of the query would have produced two distinct "2" rows, both of which would have joined to the matching `CUSTOMER` row, which I expect was your desired result. You can expand this `VALUES` list to include both ID and sort order.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a [table-value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-specifying-multiple-values-as-a-derived-table-in-a-from-clause):

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Make, Model
FROM [Database] d
INNER JOIN ( VALUES 
  (1,1),
  (2,2),
  (51,3),
  (11,4),
  (23,5),
  (2,6),
  (11,7)
) ids (id, ord) ON ids.id = d.Customer_ID
ORDER BY ids.ord
```

Knowing you have a 1000 of them, this also sets you up to convert to keeping the list in a real table that can be maintained by someone who isn't a programmer and maybe has indexes or other fields telling which values to use in which cases.